# Using greedy approach in a word sequence regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, greedy

I have a regular expression that turns the following text

`alpha beta + gamma delta - epsilon phi`

into

```
<ref4> + <ref45> - <ref11>
```

with the references being internal ids. I build the regular expression from the following code

```
EncodeRegex = new Regex("\b(?<nom>" + // word boundary
String.Join("|", Things.Select(t => Regex.Escape(t.Name)).ToArray()) + 
")\b", // word boundary
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

An example for the above text could be

```
\b(alpha\ beta|gamma\ delta|epsilon\ phi)\b
```

where "alpha beta" and co are the text blocks that i must recognize. I then replace the text blocks values with their references with a custom MatchEvaluator.

I have a problem though; if i have two text blocks A and B where A is a prefix of B, the regular expression depends on the order of A and B.
`\b(alpha|alpha\ beta)\b` will stop as soon as Alpha is evaluated, even if followed by Beta.

Apart from ordering the text blocks in descending length, is there a way to tell the regular expression always to match the longer text block possible?

---

@Anirudh: i use the following code

```
EncodeRegex.Replace(s, new MatchEvaluator(m => Things.Where(Function(r) r.Name.ToUpper() == m.Groups("nom").Value.ToUpper()).Select(Function(r) "<" & r.Reference & ">").FirstOrDefault()))
```

Comment: and what code are you using to replace it.

Comment: edited to add the replacement code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

Based on your sample text, there are known delimiters between your groups, so you could simply use a lookahead to validate delimiter like in the following expression this would prevent the shorter prefix from completing the match.

Regex: `(^|[+-]\s)(alpha|alpha\ beta)(?=\s[+-]|$)`

Replace with: `$1~~~new value~~~`

[image]

## Example

**Input text**

```
alpha beta + gamma delta - epsilon phi
alpha + alpha beta + gamma delta - epsilon phi
```

**Sample Code**

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim replacementstring as String = "$1~~~new value~~~"
    Dim matchpattern as String = "(^|[+-]\s)(alpha|alpha\ beta)(?=\s[+-]|$)"
    Console.Writeline(regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementstring,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline))
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Input After Replacement**

```
~~~new value~~~ + gamma delta - epsilon phi
~~~new value~~~ + ~~~new value~~~ + gamma delta - epsilon phi
```

Comment: Excellent! I tend to forget the lookahead when splitting along a known grammar. Two questions, though: why wouldn't this approach work with a word boundary as second parameter (see http://regexr.com?35cpl)? and out of curiosity, what tool did you use to create the graphic for the regex evaluation?

Comment: The word boundary doesn't work because your expression is missing the delimiter + or -. Because that example doesn't always have delimiters surrounded by whitespace I think you'd want to use something like `\b\s*(?=[+/*-]|$)`. By moving it out of the look ahead you're allowing for spaces at the end of the string. The exact approach really depends on the exact effect you're looking for. With them outside the capture group 1 you're effectively trimming the space from the capture, or could even move the \b and \s into the capture string to include it.

Comment: In the example I see you've also added some new punctuation so maybe this would work better http://regexr.com?35cu5.  I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds, named capture groups, or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

you might wish to try right-to-left matching if none of your patterns is a suffix of another pattern, see msdn [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k.aspx) and [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for details.

another way to go would be to factor out common subexpressions from your match expressions, e.g.

```
\b(alpha(\ beta)?\b
```

ps:
check again your code, as the engine should match greedily by default.

Comment: Since there can be some prefix in the patterns, i'd err on the safe side and assume there may be some suffix too. Factoring subexpressions looks like overkill vs ordering the patterns, but it's a good idea, i'll keep it in mind